# How to extend an admin view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I would like to extend the admin view used to create a new entry in the database.

For example I can create new books with their author, their categories, their date etc...
When I create a new book I want to send a notification to all users whose the book's author is one of their favorite authors.

The notification system is already working thanks to [django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications)

So, I just have to add this kind of stuff just after the book.save() in the admin view :

```
writer = <the_author_selected_in_the_form> # writer ID
profiles = Profile.favorites_authors.through.objects.filter(authors_id=writer)
for profile in profiles:
    notify.send(profile.profile_id, recipient=profile.profile_id, verb='New book, called <book_title>, from <author_name>')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think "the Django way" to do that is by using signals. Something like this:

```
from my.book.app import Book
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def book_created(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Notification code goes here
    if kwargs["created"]:
        notify_users()

post_save.connect(book_created, sender=Book)
```

You can read more about them in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/), also there are some [great articles](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) for beginners.